# REST Client callback: How to tell when items are done loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rest, rest-client

I'm trying to load some items from this external API using [REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

But, unlike [Ajax check for database change using route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329620/ajax-check-for-database-change-using-route), these items don't get saved to the database but rather go straight to the view -- so how would I know when they're done loading so I can load them into the client using Ajax?

**Live app which you can run on the fly**: http://runnable.com/VW9rQx-KiIFfmpII/ajax-affiliates

**app/controllers/main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Delay fetching
    @products = Affiliate.delay.fetch
  end

  # Pseudo-code from SO `ajax-check-for-database-change-using-route`
  #
  # def check_items_loaded
  #   @items_status = Affiliate.find(params[:id]).items_loaded
  #   respond_to do |wants|
  #     wants.js
  #   end
  # end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
# Pseudo-code from SO `ajax-check-for-database-change-using-route`
# get '/check_items_loaded/:id', to: 'photos#check_items_loaded', as: :check_items_loaded
```

**app/models/affiliate.rb**

```
require "rest_client"

module Affiliate
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&fts=women&offset=0&limit=10"
    )

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
      product = OpenStruct.new(product)
      product
    end
  end

 # More pseudo-code
 # Add `items_loaded` boolean to database?
 # private
 #   def set_items_loaded
 #     self.update_attributes(items_loaded: ???)
 #   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look into a pub-sub architecture using something like PubNub[1] or Pusher[2]

Your front-end would subscribe to those endpoints and then you can have your backend publish events to those endpoints (which are then read from the consumers (your frontend))

[1] PubNub - http://www.pubnub.com/

[2] Pusher - https://pusher.com/

Comment: Looks good, thanks, but is there no way I can do this without having to involve a 3rd party service?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to hack together a solution using [ActionController::Streaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html). Do take into account potential session bottlenecks.

An alternate solution might be using Websockets & Redis.